# ACPI trigger wakeup on low battery while suspended, in order to hibernate

Tags: systemd, udev, suspend, acpi, hibernate

I want to hibernate on low battery:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", \
    ATTR{status}=="Discharging", \
    ATTR{capacity}=="[0-5]", \
    RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl hibernate", \
```

This works well if the system is awake. If suspended however, it doesn't hibernate until I wake it, then instead of allowing me to unlock it immediately hibernates.

How can I make this event either work while suspended, or trigger a wakeup (and then hibernate) itself, without me opening the lid?

---

I have tried adding:

```
    ATTR{power/wakeup}="enabled"
```

without success. Indeed there is no `wakeup` currently in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power/` - actually though `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/device/power/wakeup` exists and is already `enabled`.

I gather I can't make the udev rule run while suspended, I need to trigger it to wake on low battery separately (then the udev rule can run and hibernate).

This seems already implemented in [`drivers/acpi/battery.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/22da5264abf497a10a4ed629f07f4ba28a7ed5eb/drivers/acpi/battery.c#L994-L1001):

```c
    /*
     * Wakeup the system if battery is critical low
     * or lower than the alarm level
     */
    if ((battery->state & ACPI_BATTERY_STATE_CRITICAL) ||
        (test_bit(ACPI_BATTERY_ALARM_PRESENT, &battery->flags) &&
         (battery->capacity_now <= battery->alarm)))
        acpi_pm_wakeup_event(&battery->device->dev);
```

But that has not worked for me, I don't know if 'critical low' is another textual capacity level, I've only seen as low as 'Low', but it was at the time lower than the `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/alarm`.

---

NB: I am aware of `hybrid-sleep`, but that is not what I want, firstly since I would like to conserve *some* battery; but also so that I can use `suspend-then-hibernate` such that it hibernates on either low battery *or* time delay.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this actually works somewhat out of the box. (Though battery support may vary.)

The ACPI driver will wake from sleep when `/sys/class/power_supply/BATn/charge_now` drops below `/sys/class/power_supply/BATn/alarm`.

The udev rule in my original question will then be able to run (and hibernate).

This does mean however that you probably want to ensure the value in `alarm` (as a percentage of that in `charge_full`) is the same as or only slightly higher than the upper end of the range given in the udev rule.